# Filter one array using values from another array using linqjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, linq.js

The first one is an array of objects:

```
let objectArray = [{
    FullName: "Person1",
    PersonId: "id1"
  },
  {
    FullName: "Person2",
    PersonId: "id2"
  },
  {
    FullName: "Person3",
    PersonId: "id3"
  },
  {
    FullName: "Person4",
    PersonId: "id4"
  }
];
```

The second one is an array of strings containing some ids.

```
let idsArray= ["id1", "id2", "id3"];
```

I need to delete the objects of the first array whose id are contained in the second array.

Expected result:

```
firstArray = [{
  FullName: "Person4",
  PersonId: "id4"
}];
```

Exploring `Linqjs` documentation I discovered that the `Except()` method allows me to remove elements from the first array using the second one as the "filter".

In order to use this method, I need to create a new array from `objectArray` that contains only the elements whose ids are contained on `idsArray` to use it as a parameter.

Example:

```
let filteredArray = Enumerable.From(objectArray).Except(theNewArray).ToArray();
```

To create this new array I can use the method `Where()` from `Linqjs`.

My problem starts here because I don't know how to create this new array considering that I have an array of ids to filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter` method in conjunction with `indexOf` to test if the `PersonId` property is found in the array of IDs to exclude - if it's not, add it to the new `filteredArray`. See below for example:

```js
let objects = [{
    FullName: "Person1",
    PersonId: "id1"
  },
  {
    FullName: "Person2",
    PersonId: "id2"
  },
  {
    FullName: "Person3",
    PersonId: "id3"
  },
  {
    FullName: "Person4",
    PersonId: "id4"
  }
];

let toDelete = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];

//just use Array.prototype.filter method to remove unwanted
var filteredObjects = objects.filter(function(element) {
  return toDelete.indexOf(element.PersonId) === -1;
});

console.log(filteredObjects);
```

This is achieved using vanilla JavaScript. I would advise you remove linqjs from your project's codebase if this is the only thing you're using it for.

Comment: Even though I was searching for a Linqjs solution, I ended up using this one. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the array. Use [`new Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to create a set object. This will make easier to check if the `PersonId` exists. No need to loop every `filter()`

```js
let objectArray = [
  {FullName: "Person1",PersonId: "id1"},
  {FullName: "Person2",PersonId: "id2"},
  {FullName: "Person3",PersonId: "id3"},
  {FullName: "Person4",PersonId: "id4"}
];

let idsArray = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];

let idsToRemove = new Set(idsArray);
let result = objectArray.filter(o => !idsToRemove.has(o.PersonId));

console.log(result);
```

Another option is using [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to test if an array includes a certain string.

```js
let objectArray = [
  {FullName: "Person1",PersonId: "id1"},
  {FullName: "Person2",PersonId: "id2"},
  {FullName: "Person3",PersonId: "id3"},
  {FullName: "Person4",PersonId: "id4"}
];

let idsArray = ["id1", "id2", "id3"];

let result = objectArray.filter(o => !idsArray.includes(o.PersonId));

console.log(result);
```

---

**Note:** If you dont want a new variable, you can override the existing variable as:

```
objectArray = objectArray.filter(o => ...);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Vanilla JavaScript's [`array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [`array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) like this:

```js
let objectArray = [
  {FullName: "Person1", PersonId: "id1"},
  {FullName: "Person2", PersonId: "id2"},
  {FullName: "Person3", PersonId: "id3"},
  {FullName: "Person4", PersonId: "id4"}
];
    
  let excludeIdsArray= ["id1", "id2", "id3"];
  
  let newObj = objectArray.filter(obj => !excludeIdsArray.includes(obj.PersonId))
  
  console.log(newObj)
```

**Or**, you can use [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [`array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) like this:

```js
let objectArray = [
  {FullName: "Person1", PersonId: "id1"},
  {FullName: "Person2", PersonId: "id2"},
  {FullName: "Person3", PersonId: "id3"},
  {FullName: "Person4", PersonId: "id4"}
];
        
let excludeIdsArray= ["id1", "id2", "id3"];

let newObj = objectArray.reduce((arr, myObject) => {
  if(!excludeIdsArray.includes(myObject.PersonId)) {
    arr.push(myObject)
  } 
  return arr
}, [])
  

console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take `Except` of `linq.js` with an array of objects and a column parameter to exclude the unwanted `PersonId`.

```js
var objectArray = [{ FullName: "Person1", PersonId: "id1" }, { FullName: "Person2", PersonId: "id2" }, { FullName: "Person3", PersonId: "id3" }, { FullName: "Person4", PersonId: "id4" }],
    idsArray = ["id1", "id2", "id3"],
    result = Enumerable
        .From(objectArray)
        .Except(
            Enumerable.From(idsArray).Select("{ PersonId: $ }"),
            "$.PersonId"
        )
        .ToArray();

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js"></script>
```